# Yeoman custom generator

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I'm having problems creating a custom generator for Yeoman.

The structure of the folder and files generated is fine.

If I run the generator the there no errors and all the files are correct

The problem is creating the gruntfile.js.

If I run grunt serve I get the error - Warning: Task "express" not found. Use --force to continue.

The Gruntfile.js is a bit of a mash of bits I've found here and there so it could be anything.

Does anynone know of any tutorials explaining how to do this or can anyone see why this grunt file doesn't work.

```
    // Gruntfile with the configuration of grunt-express and grunt-open. No livereload yet!
    module.exports = function (grunt) {

      'use strict';

      // Load Grunt tasks declared in the package.json file
      //require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

      // Configure Grunt 
      grunt.initConfig({

        // grunt-express serves the files from the folders listed in `bases`
        // on specified `port` and `hostname`
        express: {
          all: {
            options: {
              port: 9000,
              hostname: '0.0.0.0',
              bases: [__dirname],
              livereload: true
            }
          }
        },

        // grunt-watch monitors the projects files
        watch: {
          all: {

            files: ['index.html', 'css/**/*.css', 'js/**/*.js'],
            options: {
              livereload: true
            }
          }
        },

        // grunt-open will open your browser at the project's URL
        open: {
          all: {
            // Gets the port from the connect configuration
            path: 'http://localhost:<%= express.all.options.port%>'
          }
        }
      });

      // Creates the `server` task
      grunt.registerTask('serve', [
        'express',
        'open',
        'watch'
      ]);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to remove the slashes from //require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt) so it will load the dependencies in package.json